# Как реализовать подгрузку данных из Laravel во Vue без большого кол-ва запросов?

Tags: ajax, laravel, vue.js

Есть сделки, у каждой есть сумма, статус (id из order_statuses) и т.д.
Сейчас фильтр реализуется через такой `scope`:

```
public function scopeSearch($query)
    {
        if (request()->has('id'))
            $query->where('id', request()->input('id'));

        if (request()->has('price_from'))
            $query->having('total', '>=', request()->input('price_from'));

        if (request()->has('price_to'))
            $query->having('total', '<=', request()->input('price_to'));

        if (request()->has('status') && request()->input('status') != 'all')
            $query->where('status_id', request()->input('status'));
    }
```

А в `Orders.vue` идет обычный `select`:

```
<select v-model="filter.status">
                <option value="all">Все</option>
                <option value="0">Заказ получен</option>
                <option value="1">Заказ подтвержден</option>
                <option value="2">Внесена предоплата</option>
                <option value="3">Собирается флористом</option>
                <option value="4">Ожидает доставки</option>
                <option value="5">Доставляется</option>
                <option value="5">Успешно</option>
            </select>
```

Вопрос - как это синхронизировать правильно? Таких параметров, как статус, будет несколько. Делать каждый раз после обновления странички ajax и подтягивать данные о статусах и т.д. - такая себе идея, на мой взгляд. Как правильно это сделать?

Answer (score 1):

Можно данные скачать в модель а  опции зарендерить динамически с помощью `v-for`:

```
<select v-model="filter.status">
  <option v-for="option in options" v-bind:value="option.value">
    {{ option.text }}
  </option>
</select>
<span>Выбрано: {{ filter.status }}</span>

new Vue({
  el: '...',
  data: {
    selected: 'all',
    options: [
      { text: 'all', value: 'Все' },
      { text: '0', value: 'Заказ получен' },
      { text: '1', value: 'Заказ подтвержден' },
      { text: '2', value: 'Внесена предоплата' }
    ]
  }
})
```